# Is there any scientific evidence that verifies the advantages of infographics in resumes?

Tags: information-graphics, data-visualisation, resume

I am a computer scientist currently working on his master thesis. For this purpose i developed an application which is able to produce infographic resumes. But currently im struggling to find proper scientific papers to back some of my statements up. I know there are a lot of books out there praising the advantages of infographics and infographics in resumes. But in my opinion those references aren't strong enough. So my question is the following:

- Does anybody know of any scientific evidence in the form of papers/articles or other sources  that verifies the advantages of
  infographics in resumes or data visualisations in general?

This is probably not one of those questions usually asked here, but since most of you guys have a lot of experience in the field of graphic design i wanted to give it a shot anyway.

Comment: In my experience resumes are a special case. Bigger shops have a tendency to strip the uniqueness of your submissions of your resume and mainly work on your text alone. (by reading it into a db as pure text) Smaller shops are more impressed by bling though. Hiring is one of hose things where the science tells them, but the people doing the hires do whatever feels right.

Comment: That's a tough category.  In my company, if we scan the document and put the words in a database via OCR.  If you have lots of graphics instead of text, you won't match our terms and won't be considered.

Comment: My guess is 'no' or even just the opposite finding (that they are worse)

Comment: I also disagree that small shops are impressed by bling on a resume. A resume serves a very specificity purpose...to clearly communicate one's experience. "Bling" is usually the opposite of 'clear communication'

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and opinions so far. But I just have to emphasise that I was looking for a more scientific driven discussion. It's not helpful to just point out your opinion without any scientific proof.

Comment: @luQ if you are strictly after scientific proof then you need to ask sceptics. In anycase we have first hand proof of situations where it does not work.

Comment: It's not that I don't care for your folks opinion. Actually I do a lot. But none of that is helpful in the context of writing a scientific paper :D

Comment: You should look into automated resume screeners and applicant tracking systems. Many of these can not even uderstand anything other than keywords, more sophistucated only text. http://lifehacker.com/5866630/how-can-i-make-sure-my-resume-gets-past-resume-robots-and-into-a-humans-hand So yes while infographics might help its wasted on a robot. Might be worth searching.

Answer (score 1):

"Scientific," does not always transfer to "real life"
Having worked in the Personnel dept. of a large, international laser manufacturing company, I can tell you that when we were filling positions, and when we were sorting through unsolicited resumes from individuals applying for jobs with our company, ANY resume that had graphics was "round filed," with no time given to them.

Although humans are visually oriented creatures, a job resume is not a full page spread in Vanity Fair. It is something to qualify someone to be interviewed for a job. Not a guarantee of a job, just an interview. In our Personnel Dept., we wanted to know the applicants had the knowledge and technical skills/experience to contribute to our company, not "pretty pictures," as my manager used to say.

I couldn't care less about "scientific" research. "Feet on the ground" practicality should be your benchmark, as others in the working world have also presented you with anecdotal evidence that would refute almost ANY "scientific" conclusion that graphics are effective in a resume...In other words, "grab a clue..."

You are trying to FORCE your supposition for a scientific research paper into contradicting the position as it exists. Why can't your paper ACCURATELY reflect the truth, instead of trying to force "scientific" validation for your standpoint, where none probably exists?

Attempt to contact the personnel department managers for half a dozen technical companies, and simply ASK them. That should be as applicable as a team of "scientific researchers" doing the same thing...

Comment: I dont think anecdotal evidence has to be in contradiction to scientific. Scientific just means published peer revieved reputable source.

Comment: Thanks for the contribution and welcome to GraphicDesign! Let us know if you have any questions about how the site works